# window.location.replace() does not replace history entry in Firefox

Tags: javascript, redirect, browser-history

I have a piece of javascript code that needs to redirect the user to a new page, and reuse the current browser history entry, so that when the user clicks back, they are taken to the page that was accessed before the page that they were redirected from.

For example take the following actions:

1. You access Page A. Click on a link taking you to Page B
2. Load Page B. Based on some logic you are redirected to Page C
3. Load Page C. Click back, and go back to Page A

Pages B and C are on different domains.

I am able to do this with:

```
window.location.replace('http://new-url/');
```

This works in Chrome and Opera, but not on Firefox. In Firefox the redirect works, but when I click back on Page C, I am taken back to Page B instead of A. This is probably because of a security  limitation in Firefox:

> If the assignment can't happen because of a security violation, a
>   DOMException of the SECURITY_ERROR type is thrown. This happens if the
>   origin of the script calling the method is different from the origin
>   of the page originally described by the Location object, mostly when
>   the script is hosted on a different domain.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace

Is there a way to do this in Firefox? Just to be clear, the redirect works, I am not getting the desired back functionality.

Comment: "*If the assignment can't happen because of a security violation, a DOMException of the SECURITY_ERROR type is thrown. This happens if the origin of the script calling the method is different from the origin of the page originally described by the Location object, mostly when the script is hosted on a different domain.*" [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace)

Comment: @epascarello, yes I was suspecting of that, but I am not able to see the SECURITY_ERROR in the console. Anyway, do you know any other way to do this?

Comment: just use window.location.href ?

Comment: @epascarello, window.location.href works the same way as replace. My issue is not with the redirect, it is with the back functionality. I have edited the question to make that clear

Comment: I doubt there is anything you can do